# React useState & useEffect confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have some confusion about implementing something using React functional components. I know useState is async and does not reflect the value when you read after mutating state. However I have no idea how to implement what I'm trying to do. Basically in my React component, when it mounts I ask the server for some backend information through a websocket connection and set it in state. Right after doing this I execute a method based on a switch however I can't access the state in the method yet because I have just mutated the state and because it is async the changes are not reflected directly. Here is my code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      socket.emit("crash:info", (resp) => {
        const { status, gameId, gameHistory, mockVariable } = resp;
        setGameId(gameId);
        setGameHistory(gameHistory);
        setStatus(status);

        switch (status) {
          case 2:
            handleGameEnd({ variable: mockVariable });
            break;
        }
      });
    }, []);
```

```
  const handleGameEnd = function (data) {
    //other code with this variable...
    const { variable } = data;

    //here is the issue; gameId is undefined because it is not set by the state yet because setState is async
    if (gameHistory.filter((game) => game.gameId === gameId).length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    setGameHistory((gameHistory) => {
      const newGameHistory = [...gameHistory];
      newGameHistory.unshift({ gameId: gameId });
      newGameHistory.pop();
      return newGameHistory;
    });
  };
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you pass the relevant data (i.e.e `gameId` as a parameter to this function? `variable` is never used. I recommend a [mcve].

Comment: @ggorlen I added variable as an example because other data is needed here which is not necessary for this example. I added it to make it clear that this function accepts variables. But yes I could pass gameId as a parameter to this function.

Comment: I would consider taking out your first 2 lines out of the useEffect and into it's own hook. From there you can keep the useEffect to set all your state variables and put the `resp` variable within the useEffect's dependency array.

Comment: @Steve I don't really understand what you mean, could you possibly give an example codewise?

Comment: "But yes I could pass `gameId` as a parameter to this function." -- so the problem is solved, then?

Comment: I would try something like:
`const { status, gameId, gameHistory, mockVariable } =  socket.emit("crash:info", (resp) => { return resp }`

`useEffect(() => {
        setGameId(gameId);
        setGameHistory(gameHistory);
        setStatus(status);

        switch (status) {
          case 2:
            handleGameEnd({ variable: mockVariable });
            break;
},[resp])`
It's hard to see exactly how it would work without having access to a codesanbox example. It might not solve your problem though, you may need to defensively write `if(gameHistory)` in your handleGameEnd logic

Answer (score 0):

react like am i joke to you dude why are you setting gameHistory state twice you can do all your logic then call all setStates at the end like this

```
    useEffect(() => {
      socket.emit("crash:info", (resp) => {
        const { status, gameId, gameHistory, mockVariable } = resp;

        switch (status) {
          case 2:
            handleGameEnd({ variable: mockVariable, gameId, gameHistory });
            break;
        }


       setStatus(status);
       setGameId(gameId);
       // you already set gameHistory no need for that
       //setGameHistory(gameHistory); 
      });
    }, []);

  const handleGameEnd = function (data) {
    //other code with this variable...
    const { variable, gameId, gameHistory } = data;

    //now you have both gameId and gameHistory 
    if (gameHistory.filter((game) => game.gameId === gameId).length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    setGameHistory((gameHistory) => {
      const newGameHistory = [...gameHistory];
      newGameHistory.unshift({ gameId: gameId });
      newGameHistory.pop();
      return newGameHistory;
    });
    // you can either setState here 
      setGameId(gameId);
      setGameHistory(gameHistory);
    // or back to useEffect block
  };
```